# Sql Recursive Function only show nods that have specifik relation

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, recursive-query, relational

I have a Link structure table with ID and parentID.

```
ID, Parent, name
1,1
2,1
3,2
4,3
5,3
```

To this table I have a structure_article relation table 
in this table I have relation between a Link and a article.

struture_article

```
structid, articleID
4,1000
4,1001
5,1002
```

Every article in that table have a supplier. 
Now i am trying to create a recursive function that creates the tree 
nods if i pick a specific supplier.

Article table

```
ArticleID, SUPPLIER ID
1000,1
1001,2
1002,2
```

If I pick articles with supplier 1 then I want the function to show me the tree structure that have articles from that supplier.

I have 20 suppliers and 300 links in the DB now i want only to show articles from the suppliers i pick. I don want any empty nods.

Is this even possible do create with a recursive function in Sql Server version 2008?

I tyied wiht this code the problem is that i get only nods that have articles connected

```
         WITH a
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   structure
         WHERE  parent = 125

         UNION ALL
         SELECT m.*
         FROM   structure m
                JOIN a
                  ON m.parent = a.internidstructure)
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  internidstructure IN (SELECT DISTINCT( internidstructure )
                             FROM   dbo.articles
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.structure_article
                                            ON dbo.articles.internidarticle =
dbo.structure_article.internidarticle
WHERE  ( dbo.articles.internidsupplier IN (SELECT
internidsupplier
                         FROM   site_sup
                         WHERE
internidsite = 1) ))
ORDER  BY parent,
          sortno
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output.

Comment: It would also be helpful if your sample data exactly matched the schema of the sample query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join instead of an inner join.

Comment: The where statement works fine, i get all the structures that have the specific supplier, its the part of looping the whole tree for the specific nods that is the problem. A article can exist under 3-4 levels.

Comment: I was referring to the join inside the cte, I would need sample output and more complete sample input to be sure of the root issue, but from my experience and your description it sounds like a join issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood your need but if you want to have a new tree table without nodes not linked to a supplier, this query can work.

```
WITH A AS
(
SELECT S.ID as ID, S.Parent as Parent, 1 as art_linked
FROM   structure S
       INNER JOIN dbo.structure_article SA 
            ON S.ID = SA.structid
       INNER JOIN Article AR
            ON  AR.ArticleID = SA.ArticleID
WHERE  AR.SupplierID = 1

UNION ALL
SELECT S.ID, S.Parent, 0
FROM   structure S
       INNER JOIN A
              ON A.parent = S.ID
WHERE S.ID <> S.Parent
)

SELECT A.ID, A.Parent, MAX(A.art_linked)
FROM A
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Parent
```